# How can I mix a big box between many small boxes with flex box?

Tags: javascript, html, flexbox

I need to start with 12 boxes of the same size and then bring in a bigger box that hides or takes up the space of the previous small box after clicking html.
Is it possible with flex-box or do you definitely need a different technique?
I'm working with vanilla JavaScript and html with some css.

[image]

I am attaching a functional example [here:](http:////jsfiddle.net/nazimba/xuywkb49)

```js
// "use strict";
onload = function() {

  /////// MAIN GRID
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  let cla = document.createAttribute("class");
  cla.value = "mainGrid";
  container.setAttributeNode(cla);
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  let newWidth = 150;
  let width = 320;
  let height = 180;
  let imageRatio = height / width;
  let colors = ['#CC0000', '#00CC00', '#0000CC'];

  ///// THUMBS CONTAINERS
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);

    let divThumb = document.createElement("div"); // TILE CONTAINER
    let id = document.createAttribute("id");
    let thumbNumber = String(i).padStart(4, "0");
    id.value = thumbNumber;
    let divClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    divClass.value = `thumbContainer`;
    divThumb.setAttributeNode(id);
    divThumb.setAttributeNode(divClass);
    divThumb.style["width"] = `${newWidth}px`;
    divThumb.style["height"] = `${newWidth*imageRatio}px`;
    container.appendChild(divThumb);

    let divSolid = document.createElement("div"); // SOLID COLOR
    let divSolidClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    divSolidClass.value = `solidColor`;
    divSolid.setAttributeNode(divSolidClass);
    divSolid.style.background = color;
    divSolid.style["width"] = `${newWidth}px`;
    divSolid.style["height"] = `${newWidth*imageRatio}px`;
    divThumb.appendChild(divSolid);
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #0B2161;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainGrid {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.thumbContainer {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.solidColor {
  background-color: rgba(111, 33, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*   .oddBox { ??????????????????????????????????
        background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 1);
      }*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Example Odd Grid</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By flexbox, it could be solved only by nested grids (Complex) -or flexbox & JS masonry layout. Easier to solve this by CSS grid. Anyway, it's hard to give you a specific answer without a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi! Ezra, sorry for my naivety. I just edited the question with an example of the code. Either way, those two keywords are a great help "Masonry and CSS Grid".